# How to write test case for Firebase configure method in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, firebase, testcase

I am using Firebase in our iOS swift application. I want to write the test cases for Firebase configuration code in application i.e. line

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

I want to add test cases for

1. Is "GoogleService-Info.plist" file present for Firebase in application
2. Is app's bundle id matches with Firebase bundle id
3. If any other exceptions for Firebase generate

Comment: did you find a way to test?